# Input field with onchange fails to trigger when user click button in another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page with multiple small forms on it. Each form has one input field that has an `onchange` function which will submit it's form to a url that returns a no data status.

Things work fine, submitting form after form, until the user clicks on a small form that has ONLY a submit button in it. This click works, <del>but abandons the change in the previous field resulting in its `onchange` not firing</del> the click at the bottom of the changed function fails (still trying to understand the firebug trace).

What's going on? is there a fix for my structure?

**UPDATE:**

First I tried simply delaying the action of the submit, but no luck.

I have hidden the  and added an `<input button>` to the chain of "events" so that the focus has a place to come to rest before the real submit tries to happen -- the code below has been updated. So the question now becomes:

Is this as simple as it can be?

---

Script:

```
$(function() {
  $('input,select').change(changed);
});
function changed(){
  ... 
  $(this).parents('form').find(':submit').click();
}
function doSubmit(elt, id)
{
  $(elt).focus();
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(id).click();
    }, 400);
}
```

---

One of may small forms:

```
<form class="clean" method="POST" action="QuoteProApp.php">
  <input type="submit" value="field" name="btn_update" style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" value="000242" name="quote_id">
  <input type="text" maxlength="15" size="3" value="" name="q[cost][4][1][unit]">
</form>
```

---

The offending click goes into this form:

```
<form class="clean" method="POST" action="QuoteProApp.php">
  <input type="hidden" value="000242" name="quote_id">
  <input type='button' name='btn_close' value='Close' onclick='doSubmit(this,"#CLOSE");'>
  <input id='CLOSE' type='submit' name='btn_close' value='Close' style='display:none;'>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it because the browser doesn't want to submit two forms at once, so the one with the submit button ends up taking precedence?

Comment: I tried this, couldn't reproduce it (in Firefox, jQuery 1.8.3).  Can you be more explicit about how the bug is reproduced?  E.g., does it happen when you type text into a field, and the very next action after typing the last text letter of form A is the clicking of the submit button in form X?  Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: Taking the thought of two submit buttons, I added a button intermediate step, and that seems to have worked (question Updated for further illumination.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to create a button tag, set the focus explicitly to a it, and then set a timeout to click the real, but hidden, submit input tag. This allows the change in focus to run the submit associated with it and then continue with the explicit submit of the page.

The question has been updated to show this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Might be totally irrelevant, but your selector for the change event includes your submit input too. Can you change it to:

```
 $('input[type="text"],select').change(changed);
```

to see if anything changes?

Comment: OK, tried this, but it makes no difference. It really seems to me to be the fact that I and clicking on submit button and the FF is now blind to the idea of being redirected to submit a different form first.